# If you double the mass of a moving object - is its kinetic energy quadrupled?

Tags: energy, mass

My colleagues and I were having a layman conversation about fuel consumption of boats vs planes etc. I was pointing out that according to the formula 
$$
E_k =  \frac{1}{2}mv^2
$$
if you double the speed of an object, you quadruple its energy (which is why transport agencies do campaigns to reduce drivers speeding).

But then I was asking, if you double the *mass* do you also quadruple the energy? 
$mv$ isn't in brackets here, suggesting that a doubling of mass will only double the energy.

Comment: The easiest way to prove it to yourself is to put numbers into the equation.

Comment: *"If you double the speed of an object, you quadruple its energy"* Is correct, but  *"(which is why transport agencies do campaigns to reduce drivers speeding)."* is mostly not. The thing that drives the desire for lower speed (aside from safety) is that the *drag forces* rise as $v^2$ or worse. The kinetic energy issue pushes the wonks to rail against "jack-rabbit starts", but for cross-country driving it resistive losses that dominate by a huge factor.

Comment: As @dmckee points out, the influence of mass on fuel consumption comes largely from stop/start driving, and to a lesser extent from the added rolling friction of heavy objects. But mostly, heavier = bigger, and that has a very direct influence on drag - the biggest contributor to fuel (in)efficiency at constant (highway) speeds.

Comment: Your confusion arises mainly from a misunderstanding of basic mathematics. The question is more "how do I interpret this formula?". For your argument to hold the "1/2" would also need to be squared - so the formula would be equivalent to 1/4(mv)^2 - which is not the case. | Would you consider the area of a circle to be (Pi x r)^2? If not, have you ever seen that formula writter Area = Pi x (r^2)?

Comment: @RussellMcMahon - That's what I was clarifying. I had always assumed that energy was an exponential function of both mass and velocity. Apparently it's not.

Comment: @dwjohnston If I drop a mass on the Moon it accelerates at constant acceleration (over distances that are small wrt the Moon's radius). Units of acceleration are eg metres/second/second. Velocity increases linearly with time. If V after 1 s = V then after 2s it will be 2V and after 3s = 3V ... . At V m/s I travel V metres in 1s. So the 1st second I travel V/2 metres as I have accelerated from 0 to V so mean velocity is V/2. In the 2nd second I have gone frm V to 2V so Vavg = 1.5V. So I travelk 1.5 V m or a total 0f 0.5 + 1.5 = 2V metres in 2 seconds. So ratio of distance travelled in the ....

Comment: .... 2nd second to the 1st is 2:0.5 = 4:1. To "climb back up " takes linear energy per distance (1 Floor = E, 2 floors = 2E, ... 17 floors = 17e. So after 1s i have to climb up 1/4 of the distance I have to climb up after 2 seconds. So doubling the time has increased distance by 4x and energy vy 4x. 
**BUT** If 1kg falls 1m and kinetic energy increases by E then dropping 10 side by side I get 10 x E = 10E. So energy scales with mass and distance but with velocity squared. 
| Work through the above and follow it and it will actually make sense.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, doubling the mass doubles the energy, while doubling the velocity quadruples it. Your question is basically about order of operations; the exponent only applies to the variable it's immediately on. As you note, you'd have to put parentheses to make it cover the $m$ as well. We say that energy is *linear* in mass, but *quadratic* in velocity.

Comment: Your answer is unclear. Does doubling the mass double or quadruple the energy?

Comment: I have edited the answer to be more explicit.

Answer (score 3):

Zeldredge's answer is great, answering the question from a mathematical point of view. Since you asked this question in a physics forum, I'll just add to that by answering from a physical point of view, clarifying *why* the energy is linear in mass and not quadratic:

Suppose you have two objects of equal mass moving parallel to each other with velocity $v$, each of mass $m$, and thus each of energy $\frac{1}{2}mv^2$. Although the two objects don't have anything to do with each other, we can calculate the sum of their energies if we want, and get $mv^2$.

Now attach the masses by a thin thread with negligible mass. This doesn't change the energy of any of the masses, and neither does it change their sum. Regarding now the masses as one single object of mass $2m$, the energy of this object must be $\frac{1}{2}\times(2m)\times v^2 = mv^2$, which is equal to the sum we calculated before.

That is, if an object has twice the mass, it also has twice the energy. *If* it had four times the energy, that would mean that by attaching two objects by a thin thread, you could increase the total energy, which would mean violating the law of energy conservation — one of the worst offenses you can commit.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"If you double the mass of an object, its kinetic energy doubles" is simply **wrong**. A true statement would be:
"If you double the mass of a point object, its kinetic energy doubles."

Let's take for example a ball, moving with a rototraslational motion. Its kinetic energy would not be $$ E_k = \frac{1}{2} mv^2$$, but it would be $$ E_k = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 + \frac{1}{2} I \omega^2$$, where the second addend represents the rotational kinetic energy.

The fact is, an airplane is everything but a point object. Therefore its kinetic energy is rather given by this formula: $$E_k = \int_m \frac{1}{2}v^2dm$$. The change in the kinetic energy depends on where you add the mass on your airplane.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac{1}{2} mv^2 $= K.E. If mass is doubled then energy also doubles. Thank you 
I hope my answer is correct .